# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: reactjs

I was testing my code to see what would happen if I tried to register an already registered user and when I did that I got the error in the title with the expected *error status code*, however, I do have a catch statement so I'm not sure why the error is not being caught.

This is the state of the class:

```
state = {
    data: { username: "", password: "", name: "" },
    errors: {},
  };
```

This is my code:

```
doSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      await userService.register(this.state.data);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 400) {
        const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
        errors.username = error.response.data;
        this.setState({ errors });
      }
    }
  };
```

```
export function register(user) {
  http.post(apiEndpoint, {
    email: user.username,
    password: user.password,
    name: user.name,
  });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and the `if` function is not working at all. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: I think the `Promise` should be done in `register` function instead of `doSubmit`. Btw, add `async await` to `export async function register(user) { return await http... }` and see how it does for now

Comment: tried that but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: if you expect to have something in returns like `error`, then add `return` to `return await http.post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

catching error in `register` function instead of `doSubmit`:-

- `register` function:-

```js
export async function register(user) {
  try {
    await http.post(apiEndpoint, {
      email: user.username,
      password: user.password,
      name: user.name,
    });
  } catch(error) {
    return error
  }
}
```

- `doSubmit` function:-

```js
doSubmit = async () => {
    let res = await userService.register(this.state.data);
    if (res.response && res.response.status === 400) {
      const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
      errors.username = res.response.data;
      this.setState({ errors });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

try catching the error in the `register` function like this:

```sh
export async function register(user) {
    try {
        http.post(apiEndpoint, {
            email: user.username,
            password: user.password,
            name: user.name,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message === 'Timeout' 
            || error.message === 'Network request failed') {
            ...
            data.status = 400
            data.errorMessage = "Some error message"
            return data;
        }
        //if (catch other requests...)
    }
}
```

Then wherever you call the function...

```sh
doSubmit = async () => {
      let result = await userService.register(this.state.data);
      if (result.status == 200) {
          do something
      } else if (result.status == 400) {
          do something else
      }
  };
```

This isn't the best example but hope it helps!